# Past tense or present tense for that clause in a present perfect tense sentence

Tags: tense

“ I have never seen a smiling face that was not beautiful.”

Why do we use “was” instead of “ is” here?

Answer (score 1):

We *usually* use Simple Past ***was*** to reflect the Present Perfect (a "past tense" usage) of preceding ***have*** [never] **seen**. But this isn't a matter of "valid grammar/syntax". It's a *stylistic choice* - which is to some extend also governed by the exact meaning in the exact context.

In OP's specific example, there would be a strong preference to "backshift" the second verb to agree with the first one, making the whole utterance more "balanced, internally consistent". For the same reason we usually backshift in contexts such as *He said his name was Smith* (rather than *He said his name **is** Smith*).

But there can also be a *semantic* aspect to the choice. The way I think this applies in OP's example is that *a smiling face* is a "temporary, ephemeral" thing - that could happen in the past, present, or future, but isn't normally thought of as a *continuous* state.

On the other hand, consider the same syntactic construction in, say,...

> *I have never met anyone who **doesn't** speak English.*

It feels much more natural to me to use ***doesn't*** rather than ***didn't*** there - because to a first approximation, anyone I met who ***did*** speak English ***still does***. Either tense choice is perfectly valid in most such contexts, but depending on the *exact* semantic content (and relative relevance of Past and / or Present to that content), one might be more appropriate than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Every smiling face we saw *was* beautiful (when we saw it).

Comment: This does not answer the question of **why** we use the past form

Comment: @DavidSiegel Actually, I think the answer does **implicitly** answer the question  by indicating that that “I have never seen a smiling face that was not beautiful” is talking about discrete instances that were completed in the past. The answer may be too curt, but it is responsive.